# Can we call va_start() twice without calling va_end() in between?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

Here is my minimal example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_strings_and_lengths(int count, ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    /* Print strings */
    va_start(ap, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        char *s = va_arg(ap, char *);
        printf("%d - %s\n", i, s);
    }

    /* Print string lengths */
    va_start(ap, count); /* Is it okay to call va_start() again without calling va_end()? */
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        char *s = va_arg(ap, char *);
        printf("%d - %zu\n", i, strlen(s));
    }
    va_end(ap);
}

int main()
{
    print_strings_and_lengths(3, "apple", "ball", "cat");
    return 0;
}
```

This code is calling `va_start()` twice on the same list of variable arguments. The `va_end()` function is not called between the two calls. Is this code well defined or does it invoke undefined behavior?

Comment: Do you have a problem with adding `va_end` before the second `va_start`?

Comment: @רועיאבידן I do not have any problem adding `va_end()` before the second `va_start()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C11 7.16.1/1:

> [...] Each invocation of the `va_start` and `va_copy` macros shall be matched by a corresponding invocation of the `va_end` macro in the same function.

There's no corresponding `va_end` for both of the `va_start` calls so the code causes undefined behaviour, with no diagnostic required as the above quote is not part of a Constraint.

Comment: And to be clear, many compilers/platforms do not allocate variable size objects in va_start, but a very few do. If you care about portability, put the va_end calls in.

Comment: @GemTaylor Platforms/compilers for which omitting `va_end()` causes harm are extremely obscure/rare. Although doing so is undefined behaviour per the standard, it is almost certainly never going to cause a problem in practice, because you will almost certainly never port your code to a platform/compiler on which it would.