# Calling a function with va_list argument needs va_start() at the beggining?

Tags: c, variadic-functions, c99

A function with the following header:

```
int max(int n, va_list vals)
```

Called inside the function:

```
int max_first(int n, ...)
```

Needs a `va_start(vals, n)` invocation at the body's beginning? I tried without and it works but I don't understand which is the correct way of doing it.

```
int max(int n, va_list vals)
{
    va_start(vals, n);
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is if

> ```
> int max(int n, va_list vals)
> ```
>
> Called inside the function:
>
> ```
> int max_first(int n, ...)
> ```
>
> Needs a `va_start(vals, n)` invocation at the body's beginning?

No, it does not and it **must not**, the correct pattern is as follows:

```
int max_first(int n, ...) {
    va_list vals;
    va_start(vals, n);
    int rv = max(n, vals);
    va_end(vals);
    return rv;
}
```

then

```
int max(int n, va_list vals) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        int val = va_arg(vals, int);
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

i.e. you can call `va_start` only in a function that has `...` and you need to pass in the argument immediately preceding the `...`, and each call to `va_start` must be always followed by `va_end` for the same value, and if you pass it to a function then you must call `va_end` right afterwards without using it in the *calling function*; if you want to process the arguments again, you must *then* call `va_start` again.

Answer (score 4):

You must initialize `va_list` with `va_start` in `max_first`. But you must not redo it in `max`, because that function doesn't have necessary callframe information.

Comment: _that function doesn't have necessary callframe information_. What do you mean ?

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu You have to pass last non variable argument (`n` in `max_first`) to `va_start`, which it will use to calculate address of first possible variable argument. Your another function `max` doesn't have that variable (that `n` is different).

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with some background: per the documentation, you need to call `va_start` before invoking `va_arg` on any `va_list`:

- "va_start should be invoked with an instance to a valid va_list object ap before any calls to va_arg". ([Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_start))
- "Prior to calling va_arg, ap must be initialized by a call to either va_start or va_copy, with no intervening call to va_end". ([Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_arg))

I would imagine not calling `va_start` is *undefined behavior*, but I couldn't find a specific callout to state as such.

In your question, the function `int max(int n, va_list vals)` is not "really" variadic, since it accepts a fixed number of arguments: `2`. These are `int n` and `va_list vals`.

Per the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) "The declaration of a variadic function uses an ellipsis as the last parameter, e.g. `int printf(const char* format, ...);`"

So, it depends on how you implement it, but I would recommend documenting the `int max(int n, va_list vals)` to accept a `va_list` that is already initialized with a `va_start` call. The rationale being that it is not technically "variadic" and does not really "own" the `va_list`. It just accepts it as an input from some other source.

The actual variadic function `int max_first(int n, ...)` should be the one creating the `va_list` and priming it with the call to `va_start` before passing it anywhere.

Although, as far as I can tell, there's no way to check if a `va_list` already has `va_start` called on it or not. And there's no guarantee that it will be called before being passed to your function, so I suspect this would have to be enforced by documentation and convention.

Comment: A note on formatting: \` ≠ ". Backticks are there exclusively *to highlight code* (and other monospaced stuff, e.g. paths)

Comment: Thank you! After reading your answer, some questions came into my mind: It is perfectly fine to call `int max` from `int max_first` before max_first calling va_start? also, calling twice va_start (once in `max` and second in `max_first`) is a problem ?

Comment: You can format quotes on separate paragraphs prefixing the lines with `>`

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu - you should call `va_start` in `max_first` before passing it to `max`. And you should not call `va_start` twice without first having a call to `va_end`. This is called out in the C11 specification, as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59608709/1366973. Otherwise it is undefined behavior.